# Administator panel on Mirth will not load, but the service is running

Tags: windows, services

I have a Mirth system (Admininistrator 1.7.1.4322) installed on a Windows Server
(2008 enterprise). The system worked well for a year, but now suddenly the 
administrator panel has stopped popping up. When I click Administrator in Mirth Server
Manager, I get a popup that says Java 6 but then nothing happens. The mirth service is running, but the panel is not visible/does not popup.

Anybody know what might be causing this, and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mirth is Java-based software. Uninstalling java and re-installing java on the server solved this problem.